# ReactJS - Sitewide Global Controls

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to have a global component in ReactJS that exists on every page, so that as the user is navigating other routes, this global component itself picks up where it left off.

For example, the user is on Route A and scrolls 200 pixels down in this global component. Next, the user navigates to Route B, but the global component is reloaded/remounted and scroll position is lost.

Would the only way to have the global component retain the scroll position, be to save this scroll position in global state (i.e. Redux) and read this value back within the component itself?

Thanks

Comment: You can use either, the  component state or the redux.

Comment: Thanks @Shahid.  This is exactly what I thought, but wanted to be sure was the best way.  Appreciate it!

Comment: Great, hope you will do the best.